# Print Data on Crystal Report using ChecBox DataGridView VB.Net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, crystal-reports

Please help me. How to use the checkbox in the DataGridview to print to Crystal Report ? So the simulation is when I check to select data in DataGridview. then it can then be printed on Crystal Report. I'm using Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
foreach row as DataGridViewRow in dataGridView1.Rows
  If row.Cells("Checked").Value = True Then
    'Copy checked rows to new database table and print it in Crystal Report.
  End If
Next
```

Comment: So we assume that the new database table as we call it a temporary table to store the data we check. Right ?

Comment: @Moko Yes, you can use temporary table.